# Bootstrap navbar mix of container and container-fluid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to mix up the `container` and `container-fluid` on my navbar based Bootstrap. Below you can see the picture of my navbar. There is link "Return back" that I want to be on the right side of my brand (only when using devices up to md size).

[image: My navbar]

I would like it to be like this:

[image: My navbar 2]

And here comes my code (unnecessary excluded).

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">< Return back</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="home">MY WEBSITE</a>
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</nav>
```

How would that be possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want it between brand and main menu?

Comment: @mohamadfaramarzi, I edited the question and added an example pic.

Comment: ok, and i edited my answer, plz check again

Comment: Did you check edited version out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it between brand and navbar, this could be fine.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      < Return back</a>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="home">MY WEBSITE</a>
          </div>
          ...
        </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: No, I want it just be vertically at the same place than the brand.

Comment: please give me a picture of what you want.